# How to Prevent Flexslider from Animating

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm using the Flexslider plugin for a slider that I would like to have users be able to click through to see the various images but otherwise not animate. Is this possible? I know that if I remove the "animation" parameter, the slider jumps around with un-easing and if I add any parameter other than "fade" or "slide" (e.g. "none"), the slider ignores it. Yes, I can pause OnHover or OnAction, but I don't want the user to have to do anything other than click an arrow to advance the slider if s/he wants to.

Hope there's a solution here -- thanks for any help anyone may be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how I missed it, but there's a property "slideshow" in Flexslider that defaults to "true" in normal implementations -- change it to "false" and the slider only "animates" when a user clicks to advance it. Glad it was that simple.